# How to add compound words to the tagger in NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

So, I was wondering if anyone had any idea how to combine multiple terms to create a single term in the taggers in [NLTK.](http://nltk.org/).

For example, when I do:

```
nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize('Apple Incorporated is the largest company'))
```

It gives me:

```
[('Apple', 'NNP'), ('Incorporated', 'NNP'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('the', 'DT'), ('largest', 'JJS'), ('company', 'NN')]
```

How do I make it put 'Apple' and 'Incorporated' Together to be `('Apple Incorporated','NNP')`

Comment: you would need a chunker/parser and then concat the chunks/phrase with `_`, then flatten the structure into tuples again.

Answer (score 1):

You could try taking a look at [nltk.RegexParser](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.chunk.regexp.RegexpParser-class.html). It allows you to chunk part of speech tagged content based on regular expressions.
In your example, you could do something like

```
pattern = "NP:{<NN|NNP|NNS|NNPS>+}"
c = nltk.RegexpParser(p)
t = c.parse(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize("Apple Incorporated is the largest company")))
print t
```

This would give you:

```
Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [('Apple', 'NNP'), ('Incorporated', 'NNP')]), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('the', 'DT'), ('largest', 'JJS'), Tree('NP', [('company', 'NN')])])
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is doing exactly what it is supposed to do. It is adding Part Of Speech tags to tokens. 'Apple Incorporated' is not a single token. It is two separate tokens, and as such can't have a single POS tag applied to it. This is the correct behaviour.

I wonder if you are trying to use the wrong tool for the job. What are you trying to do / Why are you trying to do it? Perhaps you are interested in identifying collocations rather than POS tagging? You might have a look here:
[collocations module](http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/collocations.html)

Comment: I am trying to make a program that takes each type of word and performs a function on them on the text.  For example, if the tag is 'Corp' then perform certain function.  I was thinking that I could replace the tags and somehow do it manually, considering that I'm not sure how to do it with nltk, but I don't know how I would do that either!  Basically, it recognizes what type of word it is and performs a function on it. Any help?

Comment: I understand that this is the normal procedure, but I was wondering if you know how I could replace the ('Apple,'NNP'),('Corporation','NNP') with ('Apple Corporation','Corp') if 'Apple Corporation' in Companies.